# Find image width & apply to wrapper divs in wordpress via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image, width

I want to find a way for wrapper divs widths to be the size of the images (featured images) within them, so they equidistant to each other.

I think I may have found the answer here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3724001.htm (solution at the bottom) but I'm not sure how to apply it to my site: http://amuletts.com/barbaragorayska/

Something like this maybe...?

```
    window.onload=function() {
    setCaptions();
    }

    function setCaptions() {
    var picwidth=[];
    var containerDiv=document.getElementById('#primary-home');
    var dvs=containerDiv.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var c=0;c<dvs.length;c++) {
    if(dvs[c].id=='homepage-article .featured-image') {
    picwidth[c]=dvs[c].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].clientWidth;
    dvs[c].style.width=picwidth[c]+'px';
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: So... how did your attempt work out?

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  $('.article-wrapper').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).find('img').width;
    $(this).css('width',width+'px');
    var height = $(this).find('img').height;
    $(this).css('height',height+'px');
  });
)};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked for help at wordpress and got this javascript which works like a charm.

```
var $ = jQuery,
articles = $('.article-wrapper'),
widths = 0,
target = $('#primary-home');

articles.each(function() {

widths += $(this).width();

 });

target.css('width', widths);
```

I have been told that it should be achievable with CSS. If I do manage to get it to work that way I'll post again with how.